# Bookmarked shares on a home server constantly disappearing after shutdown

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network share 'remember forever' option doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96791/network-share-remember-forever-option-doesnt-work)

Anyone know how to carry bookmarked shares on a home server  from session to session? they seem to disappear after shutdown.

Found this which seems to indicate that it is only possible after 12.04, but hard to believe that this is so and doesn't exist already- after all why bookmark at all if they are removed after logoff?

(http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/nautilus-quicklist-adds-bookmark-support-for-precise/)

Comment: Hmmm... you might need to mount the drive first. I know the bookmarks on my NTFS partition don't appear until I mount the drive, a similar thing might be happening here...

Answer (score 0):

The quicklist bookmark support provides the bookmarks on the launcher, like the image below. It doesn't affect how Nautilus itself handles bookmarks, which has been available for about a decade, or maybe longer. But I think network bookmarks might be removed after a failure to connect. I'm not sure about that, though. It wouldn't hurt if you said something about what you mean by "shares". Nautilus supports many different types, and it isn't necessarily obvious that they'll all act the same way. There are differences between nfs and ftp, for instance.

[image]