# Why do the Ubuntu 11.10 file/share bookmarks always disappear between sessions?

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network share 'remember forever' option doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96791/network-share-remember-forever-option-doesnt-work)

Why do the Ubuntu 11.10 bookmarks (I bookmarked Shares on my Home Server)  always disappear between sessions . It's very tedious to have to enter them again every time. They are not listed in my `~.gtk.bookmarks` any more, just the basis stuff as below.

```
file:///home/david/Dokumente file:///home/david/Musik file:///home/david/Bilder file:///home/david/Videos file:///home/david/Downloads file:///home/david/Ubuntu%20One Ubuntu One file:///home/david
```

I know I could use Samba preloaded mounts, but that's what I was trying to get away from