# Reset Windows share password after 'Remember forever'

Tags: windows, nautilus, password, samba

I've been happily connecting to a Windows share from my 14.04 machine. When I first entered the password for the share I chose to have it remembered forever. Yesterday I changed the password on the Windows machine, today I can't access the share...

My searches for a solution have been in vain, most suggestions say that there is an entry in the Password & Keys (seahorse) app that should be deleted, this doesn't exist for me. I even ran seahorse as the root user to see if the key was hidden away in there, but no luck.

Is there anywhere else I should be looking? Shouldn't the Nautilus app be prompting me to update my password in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone stumbles on this thread looking in vain for a solution - I've got (most) of a workaround after needing to change the Windows password again.

1. Open Nautilus
2. Choose: Files > Connect to Server
3. Use a direct smb url to connect to the Windows machine (smb://)
4. Sign in with the new credentials

This isn't perfect, you can access the machine again but browsing the network and attempting to open the same machine still fails (presumably because it's using old details).

And finally a restart of the machine also seems to fix the problem but for various reasons that's not always desirable.

Comment: check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/96791/network-share-remember-forever-option-doesnt-work